# Is this type of loss function optimizable in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Usually, the loss function takes the form of squared diff or some other operation applied on prediction and actual values. I'm trying to use the predicted value to come up with a version of input that is then diffed with input to come up with the loss function. Since the predictions are not used directly in calculating the loss function, would the optimizer know what to update?

This is the input -

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 150 * 150 * 3])
```

This is another placeholder of same shape as input that is also fed in -

```
x_out = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 150 * 150 * 3])
```

Predictions (removed the intermediate ops) -

```
W_fc_idx = weight_variable([4, 100])
b_fc_idx = bias_variable([100])
y_conv_idx = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc_idx) + b_fc_idx
y_conv_idx = tf.nn.relu(y_conv_idx)

W_fc_len = weight_variable([4, 300])
b_fc_len = bias_variable([300])
y_conv_len = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc_len) + b_fc_len
y_conv_len = tf.nn.relu(y_conv_len)

def condition(outeri, y_idx, y_len, y_val, xo): return outeri < 1000
def body(outeri, y_idx, y_len, y_val, xo):
    #Various operations that use the y_conv predictions to create and return tensor of same shape as x_out
    topcorner = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_int64(y_idx[0, outeri]))
    nesti = tf.constant(0, tf.int64)
    while_condition2 = lambda nesti, xo: tf.less(nesti, tf.to_int64(y_len[0, outeri]))
    def body2(nesti, xo):
        shape = [1, 150 * 150 * 3]
        for thickness in range(1):
            index = [[0, topcorner + nesti + (thickness * 450)]]
            value = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(y_val[0, outeri]), shape=[1])#[1.5]  # [[0]]
            delta = tf.SparseTensor(index, value, shape)
            xo = xo - tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)
        return [tf.add(nesti, 1), xo]
    _, xo = tf.while_loop(while_condition2, body2, [nesti, xo])
    #A few more inner/nested while loops in here
    return xo
```

Basically, we supply the while loop with x_out predictions and the loop applies the predictions in various ways to return another version of x_out (named xout2 here) -

```
_, _, _, _, xout2 = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [outeri, y_conv_idx, y_conv_len, y_conv_val, x_out])
```

Finally, this is the loss function -

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(x, xout2))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1000).minimize(loss)
```

Now, my question is - Since the loss is not calculated directly from the predictions or any variables in the graph (it is calculated from a tensor returned from the while loop which uses the predictions in the background), would the optimization function still know which weights to update etc?

Note: I have implemented this and the loss is not changing at all for a variety of learning rates, so I'm wondering that maybe it just can't work, hence the question.

Comment: Gradients through a `while_loop` should work fine. I suspect the interesting part of this is in the "various operations" you allude to in your comment. Could you try coming up with an example which reproduces the behavior you see (i.e. some minimal set of ops in the while loop which should but don't connect the loss to a trainable variable)?

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I've updated the code to indicate the ops inside the while loop as well. Its basically a nested while loop that draws a line in `xo` of length `y_conv_len` and starting from `y_conv_idx`. In the actual code, it creates a more complex shape. Its worth noting that these two tensors are used only to figure out where to update `xo` and all of these tensors are passed as parameters, probably by value (but I don't know). Does tensorflow know to track this type of complex changes back to the appropriate weights? Or does it just look at relationship between changes in weights and loss?

Comment: Yes, gradients back through nested while loops should also be fine ([test coverage is good](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/control_flow_ops_py_test.py#L1769)). Your example still isn't at the point where I can actually run it without modifying heavily, but more generally I would recommend the [TensorFlow debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger). Consider looking at the ReLUs especially, since those often give zero gradients.

Comment: Thank you, I'll debug some more and post a more complete version of the code if it doesn't work. So far the loss has stayed the same after some hundreds runs, the weights are not adjusting in any direction. Do you happen to know if tensorflow adjusts only those specific weights that it can trace back to from the loss through the graph? Or does it work with all of the weights regardless of whether they're used or not?

Comment: It's worth checking that everything is differentiable: if you use [compute_gradients](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L327) on your `AdamOptimizer`, a value of `None` indicates that there is no path from the loss to the variable.